# Cannot copy non-latin characters from PDF document

Tags: pdf, unicode, character-encoding

I have a pdf file which contains some non-latin european characters.  If I copy some text with the highlight tool, and paste it into another program (word, notepad) - the 'special' characters do not transfer correctly (I get other odd characters in their place).

I have tried copying the text from both Acrobat Reader and Foxit.

Is there anything I can do here to copy this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you still have this issue? Is there anything you might be able to add to help us find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Normal PDF documents containing Unicode text do not store the text as characters
 - but as references to the glyphs (letter shapes) in the fonts used. When embedding fonts in a PDF document Unicode fonts are also often converted by Acrobat to several smaller fonts - so, even if you use only one font, these references may be to glyphs in several smaller fonts not to the glyphs in the original font.

When cutting and pasting Unicode text from Acrobat to another application, Acrobat needs enough information to reconstruct the Unicode characters from the letter shapes. If the font used has glyphs named accoring to the [Adobe Glyph Naming Convention](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/agl-aglfn/) then Acrobat can parse these names (which are also stored in the PDF document) and reconstruct the Unicode text. Unfortunatly, there are many Unicode fonts, including the standard Windows fonts, which do not follow this convention - so this may not be possible.

[Tagged PDF](http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/framemaker/pdfexport.html#category1) files also ensure reliable translation of text into Unicode  -so you should be able to cut and paste Unicode text from a *Tagged PDF* file.

So, if you want to prevent this problem in future, when crating a PDF from a document containing non-Latin Unicode text always generate the PDF file as a Tagged PDF and try to use only fonts which have been created with glyphs named accoring to the the Adobe Glyph Naming Convention. Doing this will ensure that your Unicode PDF documents are searchable and that texr can be reliably cut and paste text from them.

Comment: AGNC link now is https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/agl-aglfn/ (sorry, i attempted to edit without being logged in)

Answer (score 4):

In my case Polish characters like ś,ć,ł,ę were broken when copying from pdf.

Tested a lot of options. The only one that worked really well was https://online2pdf.com/convert-pdf-to-rtf# .

So recommend you using it if you don't want to waste time trying to convert things with other solutions.

Comment: indeed it seems the best solution so far

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps,in the latest version of Pdf writer, Unicode text cannot be embedded as code points, only glyphs of the open type fonts are embedded in the pdf document.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that the text in the PDF document does not contain the right characters. What you see isn't necessarily what you get with PDF, the text that you copy from and the image that you see are two different things, and in many cases that text is just an OCR reading of the image, which probably doesn't recognize the non-latin characters.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be an encoding issue. Make sure that both files are set to a Unicode encoding (probably UTF-8). I'm not entirely sure how to do this in Acrobat Reader, but Notepad and Word allow you to set this.

See http://www.text-editor.org/encoding.htm for more info on encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Chinese PDF from which I could not copy and paste the characters using Adobe Reader. I found success however by opening the PDF in Adobe Acrobat Professional, rather than in Reader.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Chrome or your browser of choice to view the PDF, then copy from there.  Browser rendering may use a different method to show the glyphs on screen.  More in depth tools are meant to render it specifically for print handling (hence the term Printable Document Format), so copying it from your browser might give you better results.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1001405)

Comment: Why not an answer? Shortly: use e.g. Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you try to [convert pdf to rtf](https://www.converter365.com/document-converter/pdf/pdf-to-rtf). I had a similar problem my self. Good luck.